# user define page number in crystal report using c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I am newbie in crystal report I have a  invoice report and  I want to print page number on each report when print it and again open the application the page number start from last printed page number how it is possible give me an idea how to make it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use built in function "Page Number"